# kubernetes cluster-admin cannot create CRD?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rbac

I am attempting to create service account that can create a CRD, but when I bind the service account to cluster-admin, kubernetes is telling me that it doesn't have permission

this is how I bind it

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-user
  namespace: my-namespace
```

and I've created the service account using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-user
  namespace: my-namespace
```

but when I run `kubectl auth can-i create CustomResourceDefinition --as=my-user --all-namespaces` it returns `no`.

I'm failing to see how it does not permission to create CRD's

Comment: I can confirm that running `kubectl auth can-i create CustomResourceDefinition --as=my-user --all-namespaces` returns no

Comment: can you please try this?

- apiGroups:
  - apiextensions.k8s.io
  resources:
  - customresourcedefinitions
  verbs:
  - "*"

Comment: I tried  resources: ["customresourcedefinitions"] verbs: ["*"]
and resources: ["*"] verbs: ["*"]

and `kubectl auth can-i create CustomResourceDefinition --as=my-user --all-namespaces` still returns no

Comment: Shouldn't your ServiceAccount and Job be in the same namespace? Currently, your ServiceAccount in `example` namespace where  your Job is in `my-namespace`.

Comment: oh yeah, they are in the same namespace, I changed the names of some of the properties to simplify the problem and forgot to change the namespace there

Comment: I updated the question to simplify the problem I'm having

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you cannot specify just the name of the service account in the --as flag.

running `$ kubectl auth can-i create customresourcedefinition --as=system:serviceaccount:my-namespace:my-user` returns `yes`

I was also trying to limit the CRD that the service account was allowed to create by using the `reosurceName` field, but apparently, you need access to `get, create` all CRD's in order to create a CRD even if you have all the permissions for the CRD with a specific `resourceName`